# Find an element $x\in\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ sucht that the exponential is not a local diffeomorphism at $x$.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Recently I have been studying Lie algebra, and I have been solving some problems to get familiarized with the concepts. 
A problem that I recently solved was to prove that in a global sense, the exponential map: $exp:\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})\rightarrow SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is not a diffeomorphism (which is not complicated as it is sufficient to prove that the exponential is not surjective in a point).
After that me profesor suggested me to prove the following:

> Find an element $x\in\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ sucht that the exponential is not a local diffeomorphism at $x$.

For this, I got a hint from the profesor, which was to find a point where the kernel of the differential of the exponential is non trivial. I think that this could help me prove that the exponential is not injective. ( I'm not sure)

Here is the definition of the differential
of exponential that I found on the internet
$$\frac{d}{dt}e^{X(t)}=e^{X(t)}\frac{1-e^{1-ad_{X}}}{ad_{X}}\frac{dX(t)}{dt}.$$

The problem is that this is the first time I try to use this formula, and I am unsure of how to proceed.

So, I would appreciate any help, also diferent ideas are welcomed.

Comment: I used the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula.

Comment: I misspelled, I wanted to write that that was the differential of the exponential. I'm going to edit the post, sorry.

Comment: Sorry fot the confusion, I was kind of distracted when I read your last question. I thought you were asking me what formula I was trying to use here, which is BCH. For the surjectivity took one matrix in $SL_{2}$ and proved that it could not be obtained by the exponential of 2 specific jordan normal forms. This was a few weeks ago, and since we saw the BCH formula recently and the diff of the exponential, the professor told us that we should try this problem as an exercise, considering that we proved the global part a weeks ago, but as I see, knowing how to solve the global prob is not helping

Comment: Hint: Rather than using any more complicated formulae, I would consider the kernel of $\exp$.